# How to dynamically load models for Sentiment analysis if they have different column names in ML .net?

Tags: c#, sentiment-analysis, ml.net

I use mapping now like this.

```
var trainedModel = _mlContext.Model.Load(modelPath, out DataViewSchema inputSchema);

_mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<SentimentIssue, SentimentPrediction>(trainedModel);

public class SentimentIssue
    {
        [LoadColumn(0)]
        public bool Label { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(1)]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

public class SentimentPrediction
    {
        [ColumnName("PredictedLabel")]
        public bool Prediction { get; set; }

        public float Probability { get; set; }

        public float Score { get; set; }

        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

If another trained model has column names that differ from the names in the code, there will be an exception in the CreatePredictionEngine method like this: 
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
Could not find input column 'SentimentText'.

Also if I use the Column Name attribute it expects a constant.

```
public class SentimentIssue
    {
        [ColumnName("Label")]
        public bool Label { get; set; }
        [ColumnName("Text")]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

The use of such a model is not allowed since the Column Name expects a constant.

```
public class SentimentIssue
    {
        [ColumnName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Label"])]
        public bool Label { get; set; }
        [ColumnName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Text"])]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

How to dynamically map column names in a model for Sentiment Analysis to a model in code. Are there other ways to dynamically load models for Sentiment Analysis?

Comment: If your data has a header column named "SentimentText" you can call the property that and use the `ColumnName` attribute of "Label"

Comment: But how to do it dynamically?

Comment: So you have the headers but still want to load them dynamically? In that case, definitely give the DataFrame API a try to load in the data - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-dataframe/

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jon. But the DataFrame API is not something that will help in this situation.